# how to use string as list's indices in Python

Tags: python

```
     for line in f.readlines():
     (addr, vlanid, videoid, reqs, area) = line.split()

     if vlanid not in dict:
          dict[vlanid] = []

     video_dict = dict[vlanid]

     if videoid not in video_dict:
         video_dict[videoid] = []

     video_dict[videoid].append((addr, vlanid, videoid, reqs, area))
```

Here is my code, I want to use videoid as indices to creat a list. the real data of videoid are different strings like this : `FYFSYJDHSJ`

I got this error message:

```
video_dict[videoid] = []
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

But now how to add identifier like 1,2,3,4 for different strings in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `dict` as a variable name. Try this (`d` instead of `dict`):

```
d = {}
for line in f.readlines():
    (addr, vlanid, videoid, reqs, area) = line.split()
    video_dict = d.setdefault(vlanid, {})
    video_dict.setdefault(videoid, []).append((addr, vlanid, videoid, reqs, area))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a dictionary instead of a list:

```
if vlanid not in dict:
    dict[vlanid] = {}
```

P.S. I recommend that you call `dict` something else so that it doesn't shadow the built-in [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, creating dictionaries would be the most ideal code to implement.  (Although you should avoid calling them `dict`, as that means something important to Python.

Your code may look something like what @aix had already posted above:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    d = dict(zip(("addr", "vlanid", "videoid", "reqs", "area"), tuple(line.split())))
```

You would be able to do something with the dictionary `d` later in your code.  Just remember - iterating through this dictionary will mean that, if you don't use `d` until after the loop is complete, you'll only get the last values from the file.